# How to print entire number even after removing decimal point?

Tags: java

I have a number as

```
Double d = 100.000000;
```

I want to remove the decimal point and print the values as 100000000

(Note I am using java)

Comment: How does your approach look?

Comment: use String insted of Double. once you stored a value in a double its a numerical value, so 100.000000 is 100.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible. `double` doesn't store zeroes after decimal point so `1.0000` is equal to `1.0`.

Hint: you can use `BigDecimal` for this. It have scale.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid 100.000000 does not equal 100000000 and as mentioned by @talex, `double` doesn't store the zeros after the decimal point.

Your best bet is to use a `String` and remove the `.` manually:

```
String s = "100.000000";    
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\.", "")); //note '.' needs to be escaped
```

**Output:**

> 100000000

You could parse it as a `Double` then if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Format the value using `String.format` and the remove the separator.

```
double d = 100.000;
String formatted = String.format(
                                  Locale.US,  //Using a Locale US to be sure the decimal separator is a "."
                                  "%5f",      //A decimal value with 5decimal
                                  d)          //The value to format
                         .replace(".", "");   //remove the separator
System.out.println(formatted);
```

> 100000000

Other examples :

> 100.000123456 > 100000123

You can see that the value is truncated, it is important to understand that.

Note that I have set the String to have 5 decimal number, but this up to you.

Answer (score 0):

the double does not store the number as 100.0000 it just stored as 100.0 that means any unnecessary zeros on the right will be deleted but if the number was like this 100.01234 u can use this trick

```
Double d = 100.01245;
String text = Double.toString(d);
text.replace(".","");
d = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

or u can store the number as sting from the beginning

```
String text = "100.000000";
d.replace(".","");
double d = Double.parseDouble(text);
```